# Power Industry - How to determine if a transformer is sufficient for the use

Tags: power, transformer, industrial

If I have a customer who provides me with their peak kW demand (say, 1000 kW) and wants to know if it is sufficient for them to downgrade from a 2500 kVA unit to a 2250 kVA unit.

Is this determination made by simply using the formula kVA=kW/pf Is there any guidance/code/recommendation for how much "room" should be left based on peak demand?

Comment: It would be kW/PF not PF/kW. Don't know more than that as I only know about small electronics

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to make a judgement.

Comment: You also need to know the peak and typical demand. Big transformers can be run at above their rating for short periods, especially in cold weather.

Comment: @SimonB I have 2-years worth of kW records so I know the peak is 1002 kW and typical seems to be about 800 kW

Comment: For a peak demand of 1000 kW to overload a 2250 kVA transformer, the power factor would need to be below .5 - is there any chance to learn PF@peak demand or increase it to saner regions?

Comment: Please edit complementary information essential to give useful answers into your question in favour of hiding them somewhere down a comment exchange.

Comment: ((From a decade of industrial growth, I seem to remember 3:4 - even that would mean ~1600 kVA at a PF of .8.))